GraalVM native application fails to load resources on external machine
I am building an executable using native image from graalvm, when I run the executable on my machine, all works fine.
When I copy the app to another machine, I get null on getResourceAsStream, I'm running the exact same code on both machines, but it fails.
I am including the resource-config in the native-image step.
Is there something I'm missing here?

That sounds like a resource not really included in the binary, can you share a reproducer ?
